# Renew F1 visa stamp before expiry

Tags: visa, student-visa

I am currently in US and my F1 visa stamp is expiring in mid-April this year. I have a valid Canada visa. I was wondering if I can visit Canada and get a new F1 stamp before its expiry. Or do I have to visit Canada after expiration?

Edit: I have to leave US in May/June and come back in September. So I am hoping to have a new visa stamp before leaving.

Comment: you don't *have to* do anything. If you're not planning any trips outside the US, you don't need the visa anymore

Comment: I have to leave US in May/June and come back in September

Comment: @Sayan: Why not apply for the visa when you will be abroad between June and September?